How to run tests in parallel in playwright having access to the test parameters
Playwright has documentation about how to parametrize tests from using project/fixture options:
import { test as base } from '@playwright/test';

export type TestOptions = {
  person: string;
};

export const test = base.extend<TestOptions>({
  person: ['John', { option: true }],
});

test('test 1', async ({ page, person }) => {
  await page.goto(`/index.html`);
  await expect(page.locator('#node'))
         .toContainText(person); // person is John
});

And also has examples of creating many tests from parameters:
const people = ['Alice', 'Bob']; // This can be read from a file for example
for (const name of people) {
  test(`testing with ${name}`, async () => {
  });
}

However, there is no mention about how to do both things, being able to read information from the parameters, for example, where is a file containing data located, and use that to create parametrized tests.
Here is some pseudo code of what I want that does not work:
test.describe('test 1', async ({ peopleFile }) => {
  const people = fs.readFileSync(peopleFile);
    for (const name of people) {
      test(`testing with ${name}`, async () => {
      });
    }
});

Is there any way to do something like this?

Why does peopleFile need to be a describe parameter? Related: Dynamically generate Playwright test asynchronously, shows No test found. The tests run twice: once to find the tests and again to execute them. I don't think you can use parameterized values in the first stage, off the top of my head.

Because I don't want to read data from a fixed location. I want to be able to see this in the configuration of the tests. Also, I want to use this to correlate the setup tests, which will generate files at the same location and I want to be able to see at a glance from the config which projects uses which configurations.

Fixtures does not work that way, they are applied in each test and what it looks like to me, you want to apply a fixture outside an isolated test. What the documentation describes is that you need to define multiple projects, each running 1 parameter, to achieve parametrization using fixture option.
